# How to convert IEnumerable<Task<T>> to IEnumerable<Func<Task<T>>> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, func

I have a private function which takes `IEnumerable<Func<Task<T>>>` as input. I'm having `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` to be passed. How to convert `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` to `IEnumerable<Func<Task<T>>>`?

**Code Sample:**

```cs
private static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ParallelizeAsync<T>(IEnumerable<Func<Task<T>>> funcs, int maxParallelism)
{
    var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxParallelism, maxParallelism);
    var result = funcs.Select(async f =>
    {
        await sem.WaitAsync();
        var r = await f();
        sem.Release();
        return r;
    });
    return await Task.WhenAll(result);
}

var functasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(async x => await Task.FromResult(x));
var help = ParallelizeAsync<IEnumerable<int>>(functasks, 10);
```

I'm getting the following error,

> cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
> to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>>>'

Am I missing some cast?

Comment: Note that the `async x => await Task.FromResult(x)` is pointless. Just do `x => Task.FromResult(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you'll want to create a `Func` which, when called, returns that already-completed `Task` you constructed. The easist way is simply:

```
() => theTask
```

So either:

```
var functasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => () => Task.FromResult(x));
```

Or given `functasks`:

```
var help = ParallelizeAsync<int>(functasks.Select(x => () => x), 10);
```

---

Your other problem is that you're calling:

```
var help = ParallelizeAsync<IEnumerable<int>>(functasks, 10)
```

Since the signature of `ParallelizeAsync` is:

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ParallelizeAsync<T>(IEnumerable<Func<Task<T>>> funcs, int maxParallelism)
```

This means that `T` is an `IEnumerable<int>`, so `ParallelizeAsync` is expecting an `IEnumerable<Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>>`. This doesn't match the rest of your question.

You probably intended to call `ParallelizeAsync<int>(...)`.

Comment: For me, the type cannot from inferred directly in Select so I need to explicitly specify like this `var functasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select<int, Func<Task<int>>>(x=> () => Task.FromResult(x));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to `Select` that returns another function:

```
var functasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
    .Select(x => async () => await Task.FromResult(x));
```

And in this simple example, `async` / `await` are superfluous:

```
var functasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => () => Task.FromResult(x));
```

---

Note that you are also calling `ParallelizeAsync` incorrectly; by providing `IEnumerable<int>` as the generic argument, `funcs` becomes `IEnumerable<Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>>`.

You should simply be passing `int`:

```
var help = ParallelizeAsync<int>(functasks, 10);
```

Or let type inference do the work:

```
var help = ParallelizeAsync(functasks, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var l = new List<Task<bool>>();
var f = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>();
f = l.Select<Task<bool>, Func<Task<bool>>>(x => () => x).ToList();
```

for you, just change this line

```
var help = ParallelizeAsync<IEnumerable<int>>(functasks.Select(t => () => t) , 10);
```